# Get node attribute xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, foreach, xml-parsing

I am trying to get all the nodes from an xml file, but I cannot get the node having attributes such as Home and Work.  Well, in my case I can get phone Home but not phone Work.  Thank you.

This is the xml file structure:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <Name>Sam</Name>   
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
      <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
      <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
      <Address>
          <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
          <City>Acampo</City>
          <State>CA</State>
          <Zip>95220</Zip>
          <Country>USA</Country>
      </Address>
    </Employee>
</Employee>
```

This is my code in C#:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("employees.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
Console.WriteLine("List of all Employee Names along with their ID:");
foreach (var employee in employees)
{     
   employee.Element("EmpId").Value);
   Console.WriteLine("SEX: {0}", employee.Element("Sex").Value);
   Console.WriteLine("Home: {0}", employee.Element("Phone").Value);
   Console.WriteLine("Work: {0}\n", employee.Element("Phone").Value);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Wished:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Attribute` method to get at an attribute. You'll need to query for `Phone` elements with a `Type` attribute of `Home`. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Home: {0}",
    employee.Elements("Phone")
            .Single(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home")
            .Value);
```

You should think about what you want to do if there *isn't* a phone number for the type you want, or if there are multiple ones. (The `Single` method requires exactly one match. There's also `First` and `Last`, as well as `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault`, which will return `null` if there are no matches.)

Comment: Hi Jon, can you suggest me please how to solve Object reference not set to an instance of an object?  Thank you.

Comment: @doro: Yes - find out which reference is `null`, work out why, and then work out what you want to do about it. See http://tinyurl.com/so-nre

Comment: thank you for the link.  Let's say I search for an element and maybe have an attribute or not.  If present it is fine, but if it is not there?  I can still use the same link?

Comment: @doro: In that case - and this is fairly specific to LINQ to XML - you can use a cast to `string` instead of taking the `Value` property: `x => (string) x.Attribute("Type") == ...`. That works because the explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `string` returns `null` if the input is `null`.

Comment: I am having some other problem, you maybe the only one to figure it out.  Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527748/best-way-to-read-an-xml-file-without-having-equal-number-of-tags-and-attributes

Answer (score 1):

This, should get you first Element named Phone, where attribute name is 'Home'

```
employee.Elements("Phone")
                  .First(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Home");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the result contains also the tags.

Comment: I see, needs .Value at the end: employee.Elements("Phone").First(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Work").Value

Answer (score 1):

Here is your Complete Code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   XElement xelement = XElement.Load("Employees.xml");
   IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();
   Console.WriteLine("List of all Employee Names along with their ID:");
   foreach (var employee in employees)
   {     
      Console.WriteLine("EmpId: {0}", employee.Element("EmpId").Value);
      Console.WriteLine("SEX: {0}", employee.Element("Sex").Value);
     //Console.WriteLine("Home: {0}", employee.Element("Phone").Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Home: {0}", employee.Elements("Phone")
               .Single(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Home").Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Home: {0}", employee.Elements("Phone")
               .Single(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Work").Value);
     //Console.WriteLine("Work: {0}\n", employee.Element("Phone").Value);
   }
   Console.Read();
}
```